# How could I solve $\displaystyle\min_{a \le x \le b} f(x)$ using Lagrangian multipliers?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

How could I solve the following optimization problem using Lagrangian multipliers?

$$\min_{a \le x \le b} f(x)$$

Can I just rewrite it as the Lagrangian as following?

$$\min  f(x)+y_{1}(a-x)+y_{2}(x-b)$$

If I differentiate with respect to $y_{1},y_{2}$ and make them equal to $0$, I got $x=a,x=b$. Can anyone help me? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Did you differentiate with respect to $x$ as well?

Comment: Yes I did, say $x=g(y_{1},y_{2})$, but it still not works

Comment: You need to maximize the Lagriangian over $x$, so do not differentiate with respect to $y_i$. Since this is constrained optimization, write down the KKT conditions. Could you change your question by adding the formula for $f(x)$ and adding the KKT conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a \leq x \leq b$ is equivalent to the conjunction of $x - a \geq 0$ and $b - x \geq 0$, we introduce **slack variables** $s_1$ and $s_2$ such that

$$x - a = s_1^2$$

$$b - x = s_2^2$$

Assuming that $f$ is differentiable, we define the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal L (x, s_1, s_2, \mu_1, \mu_2) := f (x) + \mu_1 (x - s_1^2 - a) + \mu_2 (-x - s_2^2 + b)$$

Taking the partial derivatives and finding where they vanish, we eventually obtain the following system of equations

$$\begin{array}{rl} f ' (x) &= \mu_2 - \mu_1\\ \mu_1 s_1 &=  0\\ \mu_2 s_2 &=  0\\ x  &= a + s_1^2\\ x &=  b - s_2^2\end{array}$$

Note that, unless $a = b$, the slack variables $s_1$ and $s_2$ cannot simultaneously be zero. However, whenever $s_i \neq 0$, we have $\mu_i = 0$. Hence, if $a < x < b$, then $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = 0$.

Comment: This idea is cool, so I have to consider only one constraint each time, and I will get two optimal solutions, and then pick the maximum one?

Comment: @Jakoer Essentially, one has to look for minima in the interior of $[a,b]$ (via the derivative of $f$) and then one compares them to each other and to the values of $f$ at the ends of $[a,b]$.  This is what my answer states, though in a non-obvious manner.

Comment: what if I want to find the dual problem and then solve the dual problem, how could I do?

Comment: @Jakoer I don't know. Never thought about it.